# Multiplication Result of 2 Column is different for different method of Accessing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Here, is the first 5 row of the DataSet:

[image: First 5 Rows of the DataFrame]

I am trying to multiply the rows of the 'BirthRate' and 'InternetUsers' columns of the DataSet. But I don't understand why when I use the methods in result1 and result2 it works fine but when I use result3's method all the result becomes 'NaN' value. I have also tried running "dataSet[['BirthRate']].head()" and  "dataSet[['InternetUsers']].head()" separately but they give the correct results. But why their multiplication gives "NaN" value!

[image: Picture of result1 and result2 and result3 Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and second approach multiple by `Series`, in last multiple one column `DataFrame`, so need same columns names for align, else get `NaN`s:

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                        'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                        'BirthRate':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                        'InternetUsers':[1,3,5,7,1,0]})

print (type(dataset['BirthRate']))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print (type(dataset[['BirthRate']]))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

---

```
print (dataset[['BirthRate']] * dataset[['InternetUsers']]
                                       .rename(columns={'InternetUsers':'BirthRate'}))

   BirthRate
0          7
1         24
2         45
3         28
4          2
5          0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (dataset[['BirthRate']])
   BirthRate
0          7
1          8
2          9
3          4
4          2
5          3

print(dataset[['InternetUsers']].rename(columns={'InternetUsers':'BirthRate'}))
   BirthRate
0          1
1          3
2          5
3          7
4          1
5          0
```